# Conditional Formatting to a specific column

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm new to google sheets and I like to set conditional formatting to a specific column.

Starting on Row 8, Column D
I want to set the back ground color based on that is on the cell
If cell content like 'pass' then background color should be green (183,225,205)
If cell content like 'fail' then background color should be Red (213,139,139) 
If cell content like 'pending' then background color should be Yellow (252,232,178)

So on edit of the cell I want to check the value of the cell

```
function onEdit(e){
    var actualSheetName = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
    var allValuesOnColumA = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues()
    var lastRow = allValuesOnColumA.filter(String).length + 1
    var range = ss.getRange(8, lastRow)
    conditionalFormatting(8, 4, (lastRow +1) -8, 1, actualSheetName)
}
```

I started a conditionalFormatting Function but I can't get it to work.

```
   function conditionalFormatting(rowN, colN, optRows, optCols, spreadsheetName)
{
    var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var mySheet = mySpreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheetName)
    var range1Values = mySheet.getRange(rowN,colN, optRows, optCols).getValues()
    //debugger
    for (var row in range1Values)
    {
        for (var col in range1Values[row])
        {
          for(var i=0, iLen=range1Values.length; i<iLen; i++)
          {
            if(range1Values[row][col] == 'pass') 
            {
              //debugger
              Logger.log('Local Row ' + locRow + ' Local Col ' + locCol)
              var pendingCell=mySheet.getRange(locRow, locCol)
              pendingCell.setBackground("green")
            }
            else if(range1Values[row][col] == 'fail')
            {
             // Logger.log('fail in')
              //mySheet.getRange(range1Values.offset(row, col, 1, 1).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(213,139,139) //red
              //Logger.log('fail Out')
            }
            else if(range1Values[row][col] == 'pending')
            {
              //Logger.log('Pending in')
              //mySheet.getRange(range1Values.offset(row, col, 1, 1).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(252,232,178) //Yellow
              //Logger.log('Pending Out')
            }
          }     
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

The desired result should look like:
[image: This is the desired Result]

Comment: Is there a specific reason it needs to be a script? You could highlight desired cells, right-click, and select conditional formatting. You then would select format cells if `text is exactly` `pass`.

Comment: Hi Torey, I have a workbook that we add 2-3 new sheets per weeks. I've been using the builtin conditional formatting; however I would like to automate the process. I thought that using the onEdit event would help me. Dan helped with most of what I need, I just need to check if the value entered on the cell. For example, users may enter: 'Pass", PASS', 'Passed' PASSED', 'passed', etc. What is the easiest way to check for this on google sheet? Thanks in advance. Edil

Comment: Dan's script looks great. Additionally, you might force certain entries with a dropdown for the users instead of trying to guess every combination they might add. Just highlight the input cells, right click, select `data validation`, set criteria to `list of items` and list all items separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works on cells that have the keywords 'pass', 'fail', and 'pending' starting in row 8 for column D as specified):

```
function onEdit(e){
  var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  conditionalFormatting(8, 4, (lastRow +1) - 8, 1, actualSheetName);
}

function conditionalFormatting(rowN, colN, optRows, optCols, spreadsheetName) {
  var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mySheet = mySpreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheetName);
  var range1Values = mySheet.getRange(rowN,colN, optRows, optCols).getValues();
  for (var row in range1Values) {
    for (var col in range1Values[row]) {

      if (range1Values[row][col].toLowerCase() == 'pass' || range1Values[row][col].toLowerCase() == 'passed') {
        mySheet.getRange(Number(row)+rowN, Number(col)+colN).setBackground('green')
        Logger.log('Contents PASS')

      } else if (range1Values[row][col].toLowerCase() == 'fail' || range1Values[row][col].toLowerCase() == 'failed') {
        mySheet.getRange(Number(row)+rowN, Number(col)+colN).setBackgroundRGB(213,139,139)
        Logger.log('Contents FAIL')

      } else if (range1Values[row][col].toLowerCase() == 'pending') {
        mySheet.getRange(Number(row)+rowN, Number(col)+colN).setBackgroundRGB(252,232,178)
        Logger.log('Contents PENDING')

      } else {
        Logger.log('Contents did not meet any of the criteria')  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Out of curiosity, is there any reason you aren't just using the built-in conditional formatting feature in Google Sheets? Although this code works, I find it much easier to just use the built-in conditional formatting feature.

**EDIT (FOR ADDITIONAL QUESTION IN COMMENTS):**

Modified code to not be case sensitive with keywords and also included keywords 'passed' & 'failed'

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your help. I've been using the built in conditional formatting; the issue at hand is that we are adding new sheets (2-3 times per week) to the workbook and I have to go into these new added sheets and add the conditional formatting manually. I just wanted to automate the process. I have one more question for you, users might enter 'Pass', 'Passed', 'passed', pass', 'PASS', etc in the cell, I need to check to see if it contain the work 'pass' not being case sensitive, how do I accomplish that? Thanks again for helping out. Thanks Ed

Comment: Edil, I modified the code above to account for your additional questions. The easiest way to handle the case sensitivity problem is to standardize the string before checking it against your keyword (I used the `.toLowerCase()` function to do this). Also, you can check for additional keywords by adding conditions to your `if` statement (for instance, check for 'pass' `||` 'passed')

Comment: Thanks for the help. Edil